# 3ms Camera LED Flash

Tags: power-supply, led, capacitor, camera, led-strip

After getting some ideas (thanks to users Russell McMahon, akellyirl, The Photon...) and some extra research and redesign, I would like to hear opinions about how to approach my LED flash project. Thanks.

---

I want to use [240 High CRI LEDs](http://store.yujiintl.com/products/5630-high-cri-95-led) to build a LED flash ligh for camera shooting.
There will be 6 camera shots delayed 500ms among them. So the LEDs will be turned on 6 times each 500ms for a duration of **just 3ms**. The same sensor triggers the camera shot and the LEDs.

These LEDs come in [strips of 1m](http://store.yujiintl.com/collections/all/products/high-cri-led-ribbon-5630-smd-60-led-m-90-95-cri) (versions 12V and 24V available), each of them carring 60 LEDs. So 4 strips are needed.

Within 1 strip (24V version), the 60 LEDs are distributed in 10 parallel groups (according to specs "*60 LED pcs / meter, cuttable every six (24V) LEDs*"). Each of these groups takes 24V and has 6 LED units in series along with some resistors in order to have the **120mA flowing** through each 6-LED group (specs doesn´t explicitly say so but I think it´s the way).

I´m planning to connect the four 60-LEDs strips in parallel so I´ll have 40 groups of [6LED + resistor in series] connected in parallel. 
I want to power up the strips with a **Constant Current PSU** adjusted at (120 mA * 10groups) * 4stripes = 4.8 A

(I know I may have trouble if one series group fail so I could get higher current flowing through the rest, but I´ll probably make use of [this solution](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/AND8109-D.PDF))

---

Here comes the problem, since the LEDs have to light **just 3ms at full power** in the precise moment, I´m wondering if the PSU will be able to deliver the power right in the instant needed or if I will have issues related to the [Transient Response](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370736L-01/ni_dc_power_supplies_help/transient_response/) of the PSU. Does anybody know about this?

In case the power couldn´t be delivered within the time contraints that I need, I was thinking about using capacitors. How the scheme would be in this case?

Any ideas are welcome

Thanks

Comment: "So the LEDs will be turned on 6 times each 500ms for a duration of just 3ms."  Do you mean 500 µs ?

Comment: The strip is designed for 24W at 24V and 1M, which is 1 Amp at 24V. 100mA per segment?

Comment: @tcrosley I think they actually mean flash 6 times in 3 seconds.

Comment: The LEDs are turned on an amount of time of 3ms every time the camera shoots. This happens 6 times, every 500ms. I.e. the camera shoots one time every 500ms until it completes the 6 shots.

Answer (score 5):

***Note:*** Some of the information below is anecdotal, since my measurements use a Canon 1D Mark III dSLR, rather than specific light-sensing instrumentation

I've just started work on a strobe softbox for my own product photography studio use, especially motion capture (multiple exposure of moving parts in a single frame): I will be using RGB LED strips to get color control.

Couple of things to note:

1. If you have 12 Volt or 24 Volt LED strips, those already incorporate the current limiting resistors in each cut-able piece, so **you do not need current limiting** - Just provide the rated voltage.
2. A 3 millisecond strobe every 500 ms is trivial to achieve with most LED power supplies and LED strips: I have been experimenting with a 40-Watt LED power supply, using MOSFETs to switch power to the R, G and B lines, and I am able to achieve strobe duration reliably down to **2 strobes in 1/8000 second** (0.125 milliseconds).

My results get muddy below around 30 microseconds per strobe. My camera does not support a shorter shutter time than 1/8000, so I cannot capture more precise data.

**Lessons learnt:**

- A 24 Watt power supply used on a 24 Watt LED strip leads to spurious pulses during the time my shutter is open, but a supply with **at least double the LED strip's rated power** works fine.
- Minimum clean strobe duration varies widely between LED strips of different manufacturers, and slightly between different LED strips from a single manufacturer.
- Pulse edges get softer due to capacitance along the conductors, as the length of the LED strip increases, so connecting lots of the "cuttable" cut pieces **in parallel works better**.
- The green intensity needs to be reduced a lot compared to the other two, the red a bit lower than the blue, else a color cast appears.
- The green needs to have duration reduced by about 0.25-0.5 microseconds compared to the other two colors, which may be due to secondary phosphor afterglow: See [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/86720/14004) for a detailed discussion on the "long tail" subject.

The last two points are not applicable if white LEDs are used. However, white LEDs will have a slight color cast when using very short duration (say less than 0.1 millisecond, exact limit depends on specific LED used) strobes, due to the yellow-emitting secondary phosphor continuing to glow after the blue / UV junction emission stops at each pulse. **At 3 millisecond strobes this color cast will not be discernible**.

**Recommendation:**

Experiment with the specific LED strip you intend to use, to determine the point at which any shorter strobe duration causes a color cast. The figures should be far shorter than the 3ms specified in the question.