# Turning on eight LEDs

Tags: transistors, led

I have one trigger which is a 200 ns pulse and a clock with 12.5 ns width and 50% duty cycle.

I have made 8 pulse each 5 V and 12.5 ns width.

I need to turn each LED for each of my pulse so when first pulse comes the first LED turns on and the second LED will turn on when the second pulse comes but the first LED will remain  on.

I want to use some transistor but I cant make it works.
i can use FF but not IC.

edit:
i need to turn on the leds each at time and make them stay on until at any time i get new trigger and then they will turn off and will turn on each at time again. 
i just need take my 8 pulses and every pulse will turn on one led at time and keep them works until next trigger.
in the question they said transistor can help. i know FF can be usefull here.
*Timing diagram.*

```
               _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _              _   _   _
  Pulse    ___| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_____.....__| |_| |_| |...   
               __________________________________________   ________
  LED 0    ___|                                          |_|        ...
                   ______________________________________       ____...
  LED 1    _______|                                      |_____|
                       __________________________________           ...
  LED 2    ___________|                                  |__________|
```

Comment: A timing diagram is better than a lot of words. Please check my edits. How do you want to turn off your LEDs?

Comment: actually i dont must to turn them off but if you have any easy idea i can use it will help.

Comment: why do you need to turn on the LEDs sequentially?

Comment: Unless you’ve special LEDS or aggressive drive and wiring, the LED on time is going to be around 50 ns. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/86717/what-is-the-latency-of-an-led. It would help your question if you said a few words about why you want this circuit to really do.

Comment: Is it possible that ns should be ms? If this is to be seen by humans then ms is a million times more likely.

Comment: well i need the 8 leds will stay lighting until next trigger. i dont know when the next trigger is so just led need to stay lighting all the time but when a new trigger comes to the circle the led will go off and then again will turn on each at a time.

Comment: " in the question they said " ... Is this school work/homework?

Answer (score 6):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzKust.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A shift-register made with 'D' flip-flops.*

How it works:

- Every time the clock goes high (V+) the data on the 'D' input appears on 'Q'.
- All the clocks read at the same moment so REG2 won't see the change on REG1 until the next cycle.
- When SW1 is switched to ground the LEDs will turn off one by one starting at D1.

*Timing diagram.*

```
               _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _ 
  Pulse    ___| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |___
               _________________________________
  LED 1    ___|
                   _____________________________
  LED 2    _______|
                       _________________________
  LED 3    ___________|
```

Comment: actually i cant use clock or counter.

Comment: Why not? The first line in your question says you have a clock. I did not use a counter. I used D flip-flops.

Comment: Well I have one trigger and I made eight pulses with the clock. Now I can use only the 8 pulses and 5v source. Also i need a solution which is using transistors

Comment: Why do you need a solution which uses transistors? Is this a homework question?

Comment: @IdanAra_18 You can make a flip-flop from transistors.

Comment: yes its a kind of homework i need to take one triger and a clock and turn on 8 leds each at a time and make them stay on until next triger

Comment: You have not answered the questions, "Why do you need a solution which uses transistors?" and "What is it for?" (You won't be able to see LEDs turn on that quickly. They will all appear to turn on at the same time.) Please edit your question to explain. If it is homework then please give the complete question that you have been asked.

Comment: oh well i need the led stay turn on all the time and not on and off.
i will edit my question

Comment: I see your update. You haven't updated the timing diagram to show the reset (trigger) requirement and you haven't explained why you need to use transistors. OK, if you are not going to answer the questions I can't help any more.

Comment: i dont must use transistor i will update it now sorry

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a shift register (for example 74HC595) or a decade counter (?). Search also for other models than those mentioned as example, and chose the one you prefer.
If it's just an indicator led (max 8mA) you can drive them directly form these ICs. If they are power leds, consider adding a transistor mosfet to increase current and voltage.

Comment: If you mean the CD4017 then that isn't suitable. It only turns on one LED at a time. (It's a Johnson counter, not a shift register.)

Comment: Please let us know where we can get a 74HC595 that will run at 80MHz. Where can we find a CD4017 that will operate at 8MHz, much less at 80MHz? Who makes a CD4017 or 74HC595 that can provide 20mA to an LED? Links to the datasheets would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where does the 20mA come from? Anyway LED's don't need 20mA these days. A high efficiency LED can work perfectly from 1mA.

Comment: Transistor. I didn't remember exactly. You must be right. Maybe there are simple counters with increment instead of one at a time? Does have to be a sophisticated shift register but it depends what you want to do.

Comment: Eillot Alderson Where does the OP speaks about such frequency. At such speed he can turn everything on at the same time as well. Doesn't make any sens. Most IC's (not all) provides up to 20 mA, that why I wrote "max". As Oldfart said, SMD leds can be lit with 1 or 2 mA.

Comment: The OP said they have a clock with a period of 12.5ns. Do the math. "Most ICs...provides up to 20mA" No, clearly that is false because neither of the ICs you specify can provide 20mA. You can't just make stuff up here.

Comment: Eillot Alderson  The datasheet says 8 mA. 20 mA is absolute max rating. Sorry. I will correct it. About the clock period, then I don't understand why he wants to turn leds one after the other. It won;t be visible by a human eye. He could turn all of them at the same time with a simple switch and the visual effect will be the same. IMO he uses a much more slower clock frequency, just a few Hz, but the pulse width is 12.5ns. Not clear to me.

Comment: @Fredled: If you want to make sure someone sees your comment you need to ping them with `@username` (with no spaces in the name). You can only ping one user per comment.

Comment: @Transistor Thank! :)

Comment: @Jasen The only difference I see is the use of reset. There is a storage register reset instead of output disable, It depends on how you want to use it.

Comment: the difference is maximum clock speed (80MHz required)  74LV595A is fast enough (on a 5V supply)  74HC is too slow (oops sorry deleted that comment)

Comment: well i cant use any clock or counter. i have to use transistor or Amplifier.

Comment: @IdanAra_18 You said you have a pulse. This pulse is the clock.